# Efficiency of unordered_map with custom class

Tags: c++, unordered-map

I am using the unordered_map with custom classes with dynamic memory allocation as both the key and the value. I am wondering how to efficiently insert keys and especially find values associated to specific keys.
Let

```
typedef std::unordered_map<Key,Node> Hashtable;
```

where

```
class Key {

public:

    int dimx;
    int *l;

    // allocate
    void allocate(int dim){
        l    = new int[dim];
        dimx = dim;
    }

    // ==
    bool operator==(const Key &other) const
    {
    int j;
    for(j = 0; j < dimx; j++){
        if(l[j] != other.l[j]){
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
    }

};

class Node {
public:

    double *x, *f;

    // allocate
    void allocate(int dim){
        x = new double[dim];
        f = new double[dim];
    }

};
```

and Key has a custom-made hashfunction

```
template <class T>
inline void hash_combine(std::size_t & seed, const T & v)
{

    std::hash<T> hasher;
    seed ^= hasher(v) + 0x9e3779b9 + (seed << 6) + (seed >> 2);

}

namespace std
{
  template <>
  struct hash<Key>
  {

    std::size_t operator()(const Key& key) const
    {
      std::size_t seed = 0;
      int j;
      for(j = 0; j < key.dimx; j++){
        hash_combine(seed,key.l[j]);
      }
      return seed;
    }
  };

}
```

We can then insert keys and values by

```
int dim = 2
Hashtable *hashtable = new Hashtable;

Key *keya = new Key;
key->allocate(dim);
// set values of key

Node *nodea = new Node;
node->allocate(dim);
// set values of node

hashtable->insert(std::make_pair(*key,*node))
```

Given a key we can then find a node by:

```
Node node = (hashtable->find(*key))->second;
```

I have profiled my code and concluded that multiple calls to hashtable->find is the most expensive part. Could I do something faster? Should the unorder_map e.g. be in terms of pointers to the classes?

Comment: Why are you using dynamically allocated array's instead of `std::vector` in your classes?

Comment: And why two-step initialization. Create proper constructor and use `emplace` to avoid excessive copying (You do have a proper copy constructor, right?)

Comment: which part of find is the most expensive? have you enabled optimisations? how long are the arrays?

Comment: @NathanOliver I believe I could, but I worry about performance.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot I can see your point, but would it speed up the find operation?

Comment: @Richard Hodges All optimizations enabled, dim is like 5-10, not sure what you mean with which part of find...

Comment: @JeppeDruedahl `find` calls other function internally. Profiler should show what it calls and what takes more time. It might be that problem is in your hash function. Problem might be in comparison, or something else. We need more precise results to help you.